# Export Swing JTable to Excel with HTML Tags

Tags: java, html, swing, excel, jtable

How to export `JTable` with colors to excel? Since HTML tags are included excel does not render table correctly, only HTML tag gets viewed.

Comment: what do you mean "with colors"? Do you have the html in your table data?

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure exactly what you mean however I would guess however if you break it down various tasks then firstly you will need to iterate of the rows and columns of the TableModel associated with your table and build an HTML String

```
TableModel model = table.getModel();
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder("<html><table>");
//for each row append <tr>
//for each column append<td> + model value for row,col
//close </td>
//close</tr>
builder.append("</table></html>";
```

If you saved this out to a .html file then Excel should open it.

I also have a project here that will convert HTML to Excel spreadsheets with support for styling via css:

https://github.com/alanhay/html-exporter

Maybe you could then try that to transform your generated HTML to proper .xlsx file or maybe the source will give you some further ideas.